# objective-c nsarray to c array

Tags: c, cocoa, nsarray

Sorry, I'm not even sure how to ask, since I'm a complete newbie at C, pointers and stuff like that. There's a function that accepts an argument: `char **arg`. If I write that argument like so:

```
char *cargs[] = {"blah", NULL};
```

and pass it to the function:

```
function(cargs);
```

it works. but ... I have an `NSArray` of `NSStrings` and I need to make this array out of values from `NSArray`. I figured it should be a matter of creating a C array of the same element count as `NSArray` and copy the strings, converting them with `cStringUsingEncoding`. But I honestly have no idea how to do this, since I get confused with all those pointers and such. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the rough steps can be:

1. use *count* method of NSArray to know how many NSStrings are there in the NSArray.
2. use malloc to allocate memory for cargs, something like this

   ```
   char **cargs = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * count);
   ```

   by your example, you may need to one more room for NULL which will be at the end of cargs.
3. use a loop and *objectAtIndex:* of NSArray to get out the NSStrings, like
   NSString *nsstring = [array objectAtIndex:index];
4. use method *cStringUsingEncoding:* to get the c-string out, better make a copy
5. put these c-string pointers in cargs
6. pass cargs to your function, clean and free things needed to.

It's a lot of work. 'Cause the mix of c and obj-c stuff. And a lot of manual malloc and free , messy stuff. Can't you avoid it?

--add sample code--

I'm not quite sure what your real intent is. Hope this will help.

```
void func(char **arg)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; arg[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%d=%s\n", i, arg[i]);
}
}
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *s1 = [NSString stringWithString:@"first"];
    NSString *s2 = [NSString stringWithString:@"second"];
    NSString *s3 = [NSString stringWithString:@"third"];

    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: s1, s2, s3, nil];
    //by now, we have an NSArray of three NSStrings

    int count = [array count];
    char **cargs = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * (count + 1));
    //cargs is a pointer to 4 pointers to char

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        NSString *s = [array objectAtIndex:i];//get a NSString
        const char *cstr = [s cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];//get cstring
        int len = strlen(cstr);//get its length
        char *cstr_copy = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));//allocate memory, + 1 for ending '\0'
        strcpy(cstr_copy, cstr);//make a copy
        cargs[i] = cstr_copy;//put the point in cargs
    }
    cargs[i] = NULL;

    func(cargs);//call the function to do something

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        free(cargs[i]);
    }
    free(cargs);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why send `lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:`? `cStringUsingEncoding:` will automatically create a string of the right length; indeed, you can't tell it to use a different length.

Comment: Well, i'd be glad to avoid it, but i'm using AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges to run a shell script with elevated privileges and i don't know any other way to do it.

Comment: char* arg;
 arg = (char *)malloc([a count] + 1);
 
 for (int i = 0; i < [a count]; i++)
 {
  arg[i] = [[a get:i] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding][0];
 }
 
 arg[[a count]] = 0;

This is what i've come up with with the help of my friend, but it breaks the AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges ...

How do i format the code in the comment? :(

Comment: Well, the problem actually is ... how do i assign a cString to that array's element? I've tried: arg[1] = "test" - works.  *arg[1] = [@"test" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding][0]; - doesn't work

Comment: Marius: `cStringUsingEncoding:` returns a C string. A C string is an array of characters (`char`), ending with a zero byte (`'\0'`); `cStringUsingEncoding:` returns the address of that array of characters. Saying `[…cStringUsingEncoding:…][0]` takes the first `char` in the array—the first character of the C string. Don't try to access a specific character of the string; set `arg[i]` to the pointer to the whole string, as returned by `cStringUsingEncoding:`.

Comment: @Marius, I added a sample code. Hope it'll help. By the way, I think you don't quite understand "pointer" and "pointer to pointer". Maybe that is the problem :)

Comment: The problem is i'm totally new with pointers so i simply don't know where to put those * or & symbols to make it work. Obviously, arg[i] = cString... doesn't work. Never mind, i've just read more carefuly to what you've written and tried arg[i] = *cString... It gave a warning (something about casting). So i've tried arg[i] = (char *)cString.... and it worked. Again, i'm not sure if i did it right or not, but it seems to work.

Comment: There is a fun youtube video about pointers. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnXkiAKbUPg   Take your time and learn it. Enjoy. :) Keypoint: do you understand why cargs is " char ** "? Two stars.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! @yeahnan: do i really need to make a strcopy of the cstring? I won't need it later, it's just gonna live in a current method and that's it.

Comment: The document of cStringUsingEncoding: "The returned C string is guaranteed to be valid only until either the receiver is freed, or until the current autorelease pool is emptied, whichever occurs first. ", I think it's ok to not make a copy for your case.

Comment: Marius: I wrote a tutorial about pointers a few years ago. Read it the whole way through: http://boredzo.org/pointers

Answer (score 1):

@yehnan your answer is **GREAT** - especially because *I thought*  that `const ** cStyle[arrays]` were NOT able to be created dynamically... (*I really wish there was somewhere with just basic information about `C` pointers and variables and crap...  I find the most basic "C primitives" to be far more bewildering than anything else...*)  Here's your nice little example "bundled up" into   a function... "*for the children...*"

```
char ** cArrayFromNSArray ( NSArray* array ){
   int i, count = array.count;
   char **cargs = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * (count + 1));
   for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {        //cargs is a pointer to 4 pointers to char
      NSString *s      = array[i];     //get a NSString
      const char *cstr = s.UTF8String; //get cstring
      int          len = strlen(cstr); //get its length
      char  *cstr_copy = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));//allocate memory, + 1 for ending '\0'
      strcpy(cstr_copy, cstr);         //make a copy
      cargs[i] = cstr_copy;            //put the point in cargs
  }
  cargs[i] = NULL;
  return cargs;
}
```