# how to pass Char array in a method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, char

Can anyone help me passing char array to method when i tried it is only copying one index value so

```
char c1[]={0x01};  
char c2[]={0x02};
char c3[]={0x03};
char *c[3];
c[0] = c1;
c[1] = c2;
c[2] = c3;//if i pass this char array to the below method only c[0] is copied 
 char* arrrr =[self mountLVparams:NULL :c :code_ward_arr];    
 //my method being this
-(char *)mountLVparams:(signed char *)initData :(char *)obj :(signed char *)codeWard
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c is a pointer to a pointer. your method signature should be like `-(char *)mountLVparams:(signed char *)initData :(char **)obj :(signed char *)codeWard`

```
char c1[]={0x01};  
char c2[]={0x02};
char c3[]={0x03};
char *c[3];
c[0] = c1;
c[1] = c2;
c[2] = c3;//if i pass this char array to the below method only c[0] is copied 
 char* arrrr =[self mountLVparams:NULL :c :code_ward_arr];     

-(char *)mountLVparams:(signed char *)initData :(char **)obj :(signed char *)codeWard
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;++i)
        printf("%d----%c", i,*obj[i]);

}
```

Comment: still i m not able to retieve the value is their any method lik `-(char *)mountLVparams:(signed char *)initData :(char **)obj[3] :(signed char *)codeWard`like this when i call this method i m getting **Incompatible pointer types sending 'char *[3]' to parameter of type 'char *'** this warning

Comment: try this -(void)MethodA
 { 
 char c1[]={"A"};  
 char c2[]={"B"};
 char c3[]={"C"};

 char *c[3];
 c[0] = c1;
 c[1] = c2;
 c[2] = c3;
 [self mountLVparams :c] ;
}

-(void)mountLVparams:(char **)obj 
{
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<3;++i)
  printf("%d----%c", i,*obj[i]);
 
}

Answer (score 1):

I have one solution by passing array to your function and then creating char *

```
    const char c1[]={0x01};  
    NSString *s1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:c1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //convert into string 

    const char c2[]={0x02};
    NSString *s2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:c2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //convert into string 

    const char c3[]={0x03};
    NSString *s3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:c3 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //convert into string 

    NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:s1,s2,s3,nil]; // adding all strings 
    [s1 release];
    [s2 release];
    [s3 release];
```

Now function would be like this where u will pass arr(NSArray):

```
-(char *)mountLVparams:(signed char *)initData :(NSArray *)arrChars :(signed char *)codeWard
{

int count = [arrChars count];
char *cargs = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (count + 1));
//cargs is a pointer to 4 pointers to char

int i;
for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    NSString *s = [arrChars objectAtIndex:i];//get a NSString
    const char *cstr = [s cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];//get cstring
    int len = strlen(cstr);//get its length
    char *cstr_copy = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));//allocate memory, + 1 for ending '\0'
    strcpy(cstr_copy, cstr);//make a copy
    cargs[i] = cstr_copy;//put the point in cargs
}
cargs[i] = NULL;
NSLog(@"%c | %c| %c ",cargs[0],cargs[1],cargs[2]);
return cargs;
}
```

Credit for creation of char from array of string goes to @yehnan follow  [objective-c nsarray to c array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091251/objective-c-nsarray-to-c-array)

Use like this:

```
  char *cs = [self mountLVparams:(your arguments here and pass array here)];
    NSLog(@"%c | %c | %c",cs[0],cs[1],cs[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps, you would be looking for the following where you can pass the `NSString` object with the desired content as parameter:

```
NSString *_string = [NSString stringWithString:@"\x01\x02\x03"];
[self yourMethod:_string];
```

and inside the `-yourMethod:`

```
- (void)yourMethod:(NSString *)stringWithChars {
    char _ch = [stringWithChars characterAtIndex:1]; // it gives back you an unsigned short but in this case you can use this value as char without any problem
    NSLog(@"chat at index #1 : %d, %c", _ch, _ch); // or do whatever you'd like to do.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

parameter `c` is the pointer pointing to your character array. The pointer will point the first address of the array hence it is by default `c[0]`.

You can pass it as NSstring. `[NSString stringWithFormat:%s,c]`.